# Is it possible to edit domain coded values in ArcGIS Online Feature Layers?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, domains

I'm getting started on the recently released [Citizen Problem Reporter](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/citizen-problem-reporter/) AGOL App. One of the steps is to set up an AGOL hosted featurelayer. I've done that, the app is up and running in a test state, but I'd like to edit some of the coded values to be more in tuned to what our organization handles. Is there a way to do this in AGOL?

The alternative is to download the content to a file geodatabase and host it on my SDE and then serve it using ArcGIS Server, making the necessary edits in Catalog, but that is a lot of work if I can just make the corrections on AGOL...

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue a month or so ago, they don't make things easy, but I was able to find a solution--as long as you have admin rights to the layer that you want to update.

You'll need to go to your REST page for the layer and add 'admin' between the Rest\Services part of the URL:

[image: Rest Services in URL]         [image: rest/admin/services]

From here, scroll to your attributes that contain a domain (or attributes that you would like to add a domain to) and modify the data there.

[image]

*Note, that once you save, you'll likely get an error that your edit date is invalid.  The easiest way to deal with this is to overwrite the existing date with "" to clear it out.

[image]

[ESRI post introducing this](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/10/19/updating-hosted-feature-services-in-arcgis-online/) along with some commentary on finer points and troubleshooting, and the [instructions PDF](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/files/2014/10/How-to-Update-Hosted-Feature-Service-Schemas1.pdf).

Comment: Link updated to intro blog post, there's some useful information in comments, like this scripting access project: https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/

Answer (score 2):

In the last 3 years, AGOL has changed significantly. Since my previous answer, there is a way to add/modify domains that is *much* more user friendly, though the code modification is still an option (why I didn't delete my previous answer). From the Data tab for your layer, toggle the "Fields" view (vs "Table"), choose the attribute you wish to apply the domain to and select "Create List" to create a domain.

To modify the list (Or to create a domain from values already entered in the column), use the steps above, but after selecting "Create List" select the "Generate List" button at the bottom left of the screen. Once the list is generated, you will have the option to add to the domain.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the domain on the original local file geodatbase and re-published the service.
This is certainly not the most elegant solution and had some unforeseen ramifications such as:

1. sharing and edit tracking (for a Collector application) were disabled and had to be re-set.

I will watch for a better answer here as I would like to use both AGOL and Collector more but, at least for me, real world applications change iteratively with use and I need some flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to your answer, once you are in the "admin" REST URL, you must click the "Update Definition" link at the bottom of the page in order to get to the editable page and make your changes.
I was able to add a coded value to my already established domain by copying/pasting the section already provided and modifying the value.

`, 
          {
            "name" : "Completed", 
            "code" : "C"
          }`

Thanks for sharing!